# Selenium + PHPUnit: sessionId should not be null; has this session been started yet?

Tags: session, selenium-webdriver, null, phpunit, testcomplete

I'm running Selenium RC with PHP.
I run a simple login test, that completes successfully, but just before closing the browser, I get the following error:

> 23:50:09.969 INFO - Command request: testComplete[, ] on session
>   d7a1effeabc24b0b9b46ad6fdb3eebec 23:50:09.969 INFO - Killing Google
>   Chrome... 23:50:10.286 INFO - Got result: OK on session
>   d7a1effeabc24b0b9b46ad6fdb3eebec 23:50:10.349 INFO - Command request:
>   getLocation[, ] on session null 23:50:10.351 ERROR - Exception running
>   'getLocation 'command on session null java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   sessionId should not be null; has this session been started yet?
>           at org.openqa.selenium.server.FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.getQueueSet(FrameGroupCommandQueueSet.java:216)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.server.commands.SeleniumCoreCommand.execute(SeleniumCoreCommand.java:34)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.doCommand(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:562)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handleCommandRequest(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:370)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handle(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:129)
>           at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1530)
>           at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1482)
>           at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:909)
>           at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
>           at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
>           at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
>           at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:245)
>           at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:357)
>           at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:534)
>   23:50:10.364 INFO - Got result: ERROR Server Exception: sessionId
>   should not be null; has this session been started yet? on session null

I can't find a solution...
Please help.

Comment: Looks like you killed Google Chrome right before getLocation(). Perhaps make sure the getLocation() call is before testComplete().

Comment: Thanks. It seems that adding stop() in tearDown causes it to fail.

Comment: @yonran - You should put that as an answer. @Shimix, you should accept his answer.

Comment: @casperOne For me the second comment here states that the issue is solved. At least I have no idea what do answer since op state that he could stop it from failing :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the `stop()` call within `tearDown()`. Removing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding these lines in the `setUp()` helped:

```
$this->start();
sleep(1);
```